# Issue with right shift in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a CSV file, which contains data in following fashion:

```
data_id,data_text,data_author
1,"here some text...",anurag
2,"Hi, i am apsc...",apsc
3,"i am living in "NYC"",another user
```

I am doing following steps to load the correct data
approach 1.

```
temp = LOAD'filepath' USING PigStorage(',');
```

when i am dumping temp, the data gets right shifted bcoz of an extra comma in 2nd record.

approach 2:
Loading data using new line as a delimiter

```
temp = LOAD'filepath' USING PigStorage('\n');
```

it is giving me 1 record in 1 bag.

again i am trying to implement RegEx to break the bags

```
mydata = FOREACH data GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL('\\s*,\\s*,\\s*'));
```

it is throwing error :

### Pig Stack Trace

> ERROR 1045:   Could not infer the matching function
>   for org.apache.pig.builtin.REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL as multiple or none of
>   them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
>
> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.validators.TypeCheckerException:
>   ERROR 1059:   Problem while reconciling output
>   schema of ForEach     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.TypeCheckingRelVisitor.throwTypeCheckerException(TypeCheckingRelVisitor.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.TypeCheckingRelVisitor.visit(TypeCheckingRelVisitor.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOForEach.accept(LOForEach.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
>     at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)    at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.compile(PigServer.java:1635)   at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1572)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1544)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)    at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:991)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)  at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160) Caused by:
>   org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.validators.TypeCheckerException:
>   ERROR 1045:   Could not infer the matching function
>   for org.apache.pig.builtin.REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL as multiple or none of
>   them fit. Please use an explicit cast.    at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.TypeCheckingExpVisitor.visit(TypeCheckingExpVisitor.java:775)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.accept(UserFuncExpression.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.walk(ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.java:70)
>     at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)    at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.TypeCheckingRelVisitor.visitExpressionPlan(TypeCheckingRelVisitor.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.TypeCheckingRelVisitor.visit(TypeCheckingRelVisitor.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.accept(LOGenerate.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
>     at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)    at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.visitor.TypeCheckingRelVisitor.visit(TypeCheckingRelVisitor.java:174)
>
> ## ... 19 more

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [csvexcelstorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html) to load your data.You will have to download [piggybank.jar](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank) and register it in your pigscript.

```
REGISTER /path_to_jar/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage();

A = LOAD 'filepath/file.txt' USING CSVExcelStorage(',') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray,f3:chararray);
DUMP A;
```